# Does Hook let you reuse "once per battle" equipment?

Tags: dicey-dungeons

The Thief's special ability Hook lets you use a piece of equipment twice in one turn. Does Hook let you reuse equipment that can normally only be used once per battle like [Pickpocket](https://diceydungeons.fandom.com/wiki/Pickpocket) or [Second Wind](https://diceydungeons.fandom.com/wiki/Second_Wind)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, hook will let you reuse equipment marked "once per battle". Tested by using Pickpocket twice in one turn.

Interestingly, it's possible to reuse equipment multiple times. If you activate Hook, use the "once per battle" equipment a single time, then end your turn, the equipment will still be usable next turn.